# passing a pointer of different type to a function (C)

Tags: c, pointers, types, parameter-passing, size

Suppose that a function from a generic library would like to use long ints (say 64 bit) for any case, but in my program I would like to use short ones (say 32 bit). Then I encounter a situation as follows:

```
void f(long unsigned int *a) {
  *a = 10;
}

void main(void) {
  unsigned int b;
  f(&b);
  return;
}
```

Do I understand correctly that this, in fact, is not a good idea and that the function f will overwrite 32 more bits (the ones following `b` in memory), writing `0` into them (as the compiler casts from `unsigned int *` to `long unsigned int *`)? If I imagine correctly, the following, however, will not overwrite (as the compiler casts from `long unsigned int` to `unsigned int`):

```
long unsigned int f(void) {
  return 10;
}

void main(void) {
  unsigned int b;
  b = f();
  return;
}
```

Is it correct?

This second implementation has a drawback in case it is convenient for me that the function returns some other part of the calculation, and that `10` is just an additional detail of the calculation...

Comment: `long unsigned int` is always *at least* as big as `unsigned int`. So as it's possible to cause damage to something, don't do it. In the subsidiary question in comment about `unsigned char` it is possible but unusual for it to be the same size as `unsigned int` (which is always at least 16 bits), so in that case it would be even more dangerous. In the case of the function pointer's type being smaller than what was passed, then you're not setting all of its bytes.

Comment: `void f(long unsigned int *a)` needs a pointer to `long unsigned int`. Anything else might "work" but is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I understand correctly that this, in fact, is not a good idea

Yes, that is correct.

> ... and that the function f will overwrite 32 more bits (the ones following b in memory), writing 0 into them (as the compiler casts from `unsigned int *` to `long unsigned int *`)?

That's one possibility. An `unsigned long int*` may also have stricter alignment requirements than an `unsigned int*` so it could crash before even getting that far.

What you'd typically do if you have an interface like that is to provide a variable of the correct type and then assign it to a variable of the type you want:

```c
void f(unsigned long int *a) {
  *a = 10;
}

void main(void) {
  unsigned long int tmp;
  f(&tmp);
  // if (tmp > UINT_MAX) ... // possible error check
  unsigned int b = tmp;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact I have already thought about what you suggested, but thought that maybe it is a bit non-elegant and there is a better solution, but I guess probably not...

Comment: @Sasha You're welcome. The alternative is often to use whatever types that are used in the API you are working with.

Answer (score 2):

The critical issue is the type used to access an object. In `f`, the parameter `a` is declared as `long unsigned int *a`. This means that, inside `f`, `*a` refers to a `long unsigned int`. In particular, `*a = 10;` means “Write the value 10 to a `long unsigned int`.

In `main`, `b` is defined as `unsigned int b`. Then `f(&b)` passes the address of an `unsigned int` to `f`.

So `*a = 10` says to write bytes for a `long unsigned int` to an object that is actually an `unsigned int`.

If `long unsigned int` is 64 bits and `unsigned int` is 32 bits, this means that `f` nominally tries to write more bits than the object has. It could write to memory outside the object, and this can corrupt data the program is using for other purposes. It can also attempt to access memory outside the valid address space of the process, which would cause a trap, ending execution of the program.

However, regardless of the specifics of the memory access, the behavior of this code is not defined by the C standard. C 2018 6.5 7 specifies rules about what type shall be used to access an object. For an `unsigned int`, those rules allow accessing it with a type that is:

- `unsigned int`,
- `unsigned int` with qualifiers (such as `const` or `volatile`),
- `int` (`signed int`), with or without qualifiers,
- an array, structure, or union type with one of the above as a member, or
- a character type.

Since `long unsigned int` is none of the above, it does not conform to the rules. Even if `long unsigned int` is the same width as `unsigned int`, it is a different type that is not compatible with `unsigned int`, so it does not conform to the rules.

Even if it is the same width, so that `*a = 10` does not nominally access more memory than `b` actually has, the violation of the rules in 6.5 7 means the compiler might make “incorrect” deductions about the program while optimizing, and then optimization can transform your program in ways you do not expect.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. But, in more detail, even if in my code I change long unsigned int to unsigned char, there are still interesting points, if I understand correctly. I think (CMIYW), the first code will write to the first byte of `b`, while the second code will do that, plus putting `0` in the remaining three bytes...

Comment: @Sasha: Accessing an object using a character type, when the object itself does not have character type, is for special purposes. It is mentioned in this answer because it is allowed by the aliasing rules, but that does not mean it will fill in the rest of the object or serve your purposes.